# time deduction and exchange in PHP

Tags: php, html

May i ask you how can i calculate the period by deduct two time parameter like below

```
$time_1 = $rows['code_send_time'];
$period = time() - $time_1;
```

after I echo the $period how can I exchange to minute and know how many minutes has passed?

The result after I deduct is "151341193030" and I want the result will be "30" (mins) or "1800" (seconds)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `DateTime` object for this. If you check out the docs there is this method: `DateTime::diff`

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method DateTime::diff() in ... What should i do sir ?

Comment: @Ryan. You either don't have this installed or you are running an older version of PHP. It is available as of PHP 5 >= 5.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

http://snipplr.com/view/1459/sec2hms/

Add what you have to this:

sec2hms( $period );

Answer (score 0):

```
$time_1 = $rows['code_send_time'];

// As you said you get 151341193030 here
$period = time() - $time_1;
```

$period contains the number of seconds. So if you want to get minutes you can divide it by 60 and it you'd like to get hours then divide it by 3600.